# Algorithm to parse file where redundant index values are selected by maximum and minimum values

Tags: python, algorithm, parsing, pandas

I am trying to write a Python program which reads in a file in the following format:

```
ID  chrom   txStart txEnd   score   strand
ENSMUSG00000042429  chr1    1   100 0   -
ENSMUSG00000042429  chr1    110 500 0   -
ENSMUSG00000042500  chr2    12  40  0   -
ENSMUSG00000042500  chr2    200 10000   0   -
ENSMUSG00000042500  chr2    4   50  0   -
ENSMUSG00000042429  chr3    40  33  0   -
ENSMUSG00000025909  chr3    10000   200000  0   -
ENSMUSG00000025909  chr3    1   5   0   -
ENSMUSG00000025909  chr3    400 2000    0   -
```

Then it outputs a file in the same structure, BUT if the `ID` is redundant, it  combines rows, selecting the **minimum** value of `txStart` and the **maximum** value of `txEnd`.

For instance, for `ENSMUSG00000042429`, since it appears twice, it will select txStart as 1 and txEnd as 500 (these are the minimum and maximum respectively). The expected output of the above data would be:

```
ID  chrom   txStart txEnd   score   strand
ENSMUSG00000042429  chr1    1   500 0   -
ENSMUSG00000042500  chr2    4   10000   0   -
ENSMUSG00000042429  chr3    40  33  0   -
ENSMUSG00000025909  chr3    1   200000  0   -
```

I can't figure out how to get this done. I started by reading files in python using pandas, and assigning the first column as an index using:

```
data = pd.read_table("Input.txt", sep="\t")
```

Then I thought of creating dictionaries where the key is the index, and the values are the remaining line. That would be:

```
dictionary = {}
for item in data.index:
    k, v = data.ix[item], data.ix[item, c("chrom", "txStart", "txEnd", "score", "strand"]
```

That caused an error, and I can't figure out where to go from here... what would be the best algorithm to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah a dictionary will be helpful. I think you can just grab the data from each line, and either stuff it in the dict or update it if an entry already exists:

```
fp=open('Input.txt')
data={}
def strmin(a,b):
    return str(min(int(a),int(b)));
def strmax(a,b):
    return str(max(int(a),int(b)));
for line in fp:
    ID,chrom,txStart,txEnd,score,strand=line.split()
    if ID=="ID":
        print(line.strip()) # header
        continue
    if not data.has_key(ID):
        data[ID]=[ID,chrom,txStart,txEnd,score,strand]
        continue
    i,c,ts,te,sc,st=data[ID]
    data[ID] = [i,c,strmin(txStart,ts),strmax(txEnd,te),sc,st]

# maybe you want to sort it here...
for ID in data.keys():
    print('\t'.join(data[ID]))
```

This yields something slightly different than your expected result:

```
ID  chrom   txStart txEnd   score   strand
ENSMUSG00000042429      chr1    1       500     0       -
ENSMUSG00000042500      chr2    4       10000   0       -
ENSMUSG00000025909      chr3    1       200000  0       -
```

Maybe you meant (ID,chrom) should be unique? Just change the key to include chrom.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea to use a dictionary, with the record IDs as the keys, seems to be a good one. Here's a general outline.

```
records = {}

# Open file and deal with the header line.
with open(...) as fh:
    header = next(fh)

    # Process the input data.
    for line in fh:

        # Parse the line and get the ID. You might need
        # more robust parsing logic, depending on the messiness
        # of the data.
        fields = line.split()
        rec_id = fields[0]

        # Either add a new record, or modify an existing record
        # based on the logic you need.
        if rec_id in records:
            # Modify records[rec_id]
        else:
            records[rec_id] = fields
```

That approach assumes you can hold the entire file in memory. If not, you'll need to be more careful, processing the file a chunk at a time and making sure to grab all contiguous lines that share a common ID (assuming that such lines are indeed contiguous). Here's an outline of that strategy:

```
def file_chunks(path):
    with open(path) as fh:
        header = next(fh)
        chunk = []
        prev_id = None

        for line in fh:
            fields = line.split()
            rec_id = fields[0]
            if chunk and rec_id != prev_id:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
            chunk.append(fields)
            prev_id = rec_id

        if chunk:
            yield chunk

def main():
    records = {}

    for chunk in file_chunks(...):
        # Process the chunk of lines having the same ID.

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are creating your dictionary, like @FMc suggested, you can directly filter your `txStart` and `txEnd` values as desired.

If a key already is present, compare the current with the new value and replace it, if it is smaller  (for `txStart`) or greater (for `txEnd`). At the end, you will have the minimum and maximum values of each in one single dictionary item for each ID.